# can not open interface builder due to IBUIScreenMetrics initWithCoder:]:unrecognized selector send to instance

Tags: xcode, ios4, ipad

I have build a project with xcode 3.2.6 and sent the project to my partner. He is using later xcode version 4.4, and modify interface builder file and change coding. After he send the project back to me, I can not open interface builder due to  IBUIScreenMetrics initWithCoder:]:unrecognized selector send to instance 0x1b109790. I would like to know what is the root cause and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, too.

I solved it by using following method.

[image: xib configuration]

In file inspector of the xib, select "Interface Builder 3.1" from the combo box.

After this, I can open the xib in xcode 3.2.6.